# Concatenation in between records in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, concatenation

I have a table in Access that lists property IDs and the years each were certified:

```
B_ID    CertYear
a   2016
b   2016
c   2015
a   2015
a   2014
```

I want to create a query/table that will count the number of years each building has been certified and also list each year in separate columns to look like this:

```
B_ID    Count_CertYear  Detail_CertYear
a   3   2016|2015|2014
b   1   2016
c   1   2015
```

In the query design I was able to calculate the first two columns but am unable to figure out how to do the third. Here is how I currently have the table laid out.

```
Field:  B_ID    B_ID
Table:  MyTable MyTable
Total:  Count   Count
Sort:       
Show:       
Criteria:       
Or:
```

Answer (score 0):

Access does come with a set of domain aggregation functions, Count(), Sum(), Avg(), First(), Last(), Min(), Max(), StDev(), StDevP(), Var(), and VarP(), however, there is no native domain concatenation function.

My preference would be to handle this in SQL server and return the results via stored procedure, but if you're limited to Access, then using Patrick Matthews' domain concatenation function [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/2380/Domain-Aggregate-for-Concatenating-Values-by-Group-in-Microsoft-Access.html) is your best bet.

From the documentation of DConcat():

```
SELECT DConcat("Account","Sample") AS Accounts
FROM Sample
GROUP BY DConcat("Account","Sample");

Returns:
Accounts
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Acct1, Acct10, Acct2, Acct3, Acct4, Acct5, Acct6, Acct7, Acct8, Acct9
```

For the specific example in your question:

```
SELECT B_ID
     , COUNT(Cert_Year)
     , DConcat("CertYear","MyTable", "B_ID='" & [B_ID] & "'") AS Detail_CertYear
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY B_ID
```

Should return these values:

```
B_ID Count_CertYear Detail_CertYear
------------------------------
a    3              2016,2015,2014
b    1              2016
c    1              2015
```

Comment: the function Dconcat is not recognized by Access in SQL View from Query Design or Expression Builder. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in Access, you can either use a crosstab query, or use a function to concatenate the years based on B_ID.

You say that you want to "list each year in separate columns", so I think the crosstab is more appropriate for you here.

Here is the crosstab SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Min(t.[CertYear]) AS MinOfCertYear
SELECT t.[B_ID], Count(t.[CertYear]) AS [TotalYears]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t1.B_ID, 
    t1.CertYear, 
    COUNT(t2.ID) AS YearCount
  FROM YourTable t1
  INNER JOIN YourTable t2
          ON t1.B_ID = t2.B_ID
         AND t1.ID <= t2.ID
  GROUP BY t1.B_ID, t1.CertYear
) t
GROUP BY t.[B_ID]
PIVOT 'Year: ' & t.[YearCount];
```

If you want to just return the years in a comma separated single column then you can use the function found [here](http://accessmvp.com/thedbguy/codes.asp?title=simplecsv) as part of a regular aggregate query.

Then, your SQL would be:

```
SELECT 
  t1.B_ID, 
  COUNT(t1.ID) AS YearCount, 
  SimpleCSV("SELECT t3.CertYear FROM YourTable t3 WHERE t3.B_ID = '" & t1.B_ID & "'") AS [Years]
FROM YourTable t1
GROUP BY t1.B_ID
```

Comment: @ David Marten, I inserted the SQL in the second example into SQL view within Query Design. I receive an error noting that SimpleCSV is an undefined function. Further, all the data in the table I am trying to create comes from one table. It's not clear where "t3" is coming from. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: SimpleCSV() is a user-defined VBA function in the link I posted in my answer. 
Save it in a new standard VBA module (name the module anything other than 'SimpleCSV'). 
Compile the code (Debug menu in VBA editor -> Compile)

t3 is just an alias - The function works by opening up a separate recordset for each record in the aggregate query and concatenating the records with the same B_ID.

I meant to check with you that your table has a Primary Key field?

Also, make sure you replace occurrences of 'YourTable' with your actual table name.