# SQL SELECT filtering out combinations where another column contains empty cells, then returning records based on max date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have run into an issue I don't know how to solve. I'm working with a MS Access DB.

I have this data:

[image: Dummy of my database content]

I want to write a SELECT statement, that gives the following result:

[image: Desired output]

For each combination of Project and Invoice, I want to return the record containing the maximum date, conditional on all records for that combination of Project and Invoice being Signed (i.e. Signed or Date column not empty).

In my head, first I would sort the irrelevant records out, and then return the max date for the remaining records. I'm stuck on the first part.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Hulu

Comment: Why is the record: `B;2;Desk;100;J.D.;2022-09-23` not in the result ?

Comment: im get why you choose ball for a but for b desk has the latest date, also what if two had the same datem which one to choose? and basically i woud use https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303172/5193536 to get the row that you want, there you need to answer my previous questions to get the "right" number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an initial query which fetches the combinations of `Project`, `Invoice`, `Date` from the rows you want returned by your final query.

```sql
SELECT
    y0.Project,
    y0.Invoice,
    Max(y0.Date) AS MaxOfDate
FROM YourTable AS y0
GROUP BY y0.Project, y0.Invoice
HAVING Sum(IIf(y0.Signed Is Null,1,0))=0;
```

The `HAVING` clause discards any `Project`/`Invoice` groups which include a row with a Null in the `Signed` column.

If you save that query as `qryTargetRows`, you can then join it back to your original table to select the matching rows.

```sql
SELECT
    y1.Project,
    y1.Invoice,
    y1.Desc,
    y1.Value,
    y1.Signed,
    y1.Date
FROM
    YourTable AS y1
    INNER JOIN qryTargetRows AS sub
    ON (y1.Project = sub.Project)
    AND (y1.Invoice = sub.Invoice)
    AND (y1.Date = sub.MaxOfDate);
```

Or you can do it without the saved query by directly including its SQL as a subquery.

```sql
SELECT
    y1.Project,
    y1.Invoice,
    y1.Desc,
    y1.Value,
    y1.Signed,
    y1.Date
FROM
    YourTable AS y1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT y0.Project, y0.Invoice, Max(y0.Date) AS MaxOfDate
        FROM YourTable AS y0
        GROUP BY y0.Project, y0.Invoice
        HAVING Sum(IIf(y0.Signed Is Null,1,0))=0
    ) AS sub
    ON (y1.Project = sub.Project)
    AND (y1.Invoice = sub.Invoice)
    AND (y1.Date = sub.MaxOfDate);
```

Comment: Solved the problem according to my specification. Should mention that, as @nbk points out, I did not specify which record to choose if there are multiple records for one set of Project/Invoice with same MaxOfDate. By implementing this solution, they all come out as separate records - which is totally fine for the use-case. Impressed by the support on the forum - you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Write A SQL query, which should be possible in MS-Access too, like this:

```sql
SELECT
   Project,
   Invoice,
   MIN([Desc]) Descriptions,
   SUM(Value) Value,
   MIN(Signed) Signed,
   MAX([Date]) "Date"
FROM data
WHERE Signed<>'' AND [Date]<>''
GROUP BY 
   Project,
   Invoice
```

output:

| Project | Invoice | Descriptions | Value | Signed | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Ball | 100 | J.D. | 2022-09-20 |
| B | 1 | Sofa | 300 | J.D. | 2022-09-22 |
| B | 2 | Desk | 100 | J.D. | 2022-09-23 |

Note: for invoice 1 on project A, you will see a value of 300, which is the total for that invoice (when grouping on `Project='A' and Invoice=1`).

Maybe I should have used DCONCAT (see: [Concatenation in between records in Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103191/concatenation-in-between-records-in-access-query) ) for the Description, to include 'TV' in it. But I am unable to test that so I am only referring to this answer.

Comment: Access SQL requires `AS` operator and does not use double quotes for identifiers per SQL standard.

Comment: @Parfait: It's OK when you do an edit, and correct those mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Luuk. However, as there is a blank in Signed/Date for one of the records in the B/2 combination, I do not want that to come out. The solution from @HansUp takes care of that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining a second query:

```sql
Select *
From YourTable As T
Inner Join
    (Select Project, Invoice, Max([Date]) As MaxDate
    From YourTable 
    Group By Project, Invoice) As S
    On T.Project = S.Project And T.Invoice = S.Invoice And T.Date = S.MaxDate
```

Comment: Does not account for "...conditional on all records for that combination of Project and Invoice being Signed (i.e. Signed or Date column not empty)". Now solved. Appreciate the effort.